# How many children can sleep in a room of a given size in Illinois?

Tags: illinois, parental-rights

I'm going through a parenting plan modification. Currently my kid has overnights, and there are three kids (7, 11 and my son 4) sleeping in a 108 sq ft room with three beds... I do not think this is adequate.

Is there any legal limit on how many children can sleep in a room of a given size in Illinois?

Comment: Is there a reason you think this is inadequate, beyond a suspicion that the law disallows it?

Comment: There is no room to do anything in the room. Barely enough room to walk in it

Comment: Well, it is a bedroom. If you can walk from door to bed and back, and sleep in it, it appears to be perfect.

Comment: I understand that, but if you had 3 kids in one room, would that be acceptable? No toys, to, room to walk?

Comment: Can each kid walk from door to bed and back, and sleep in the room? Toys are not necessary for sleep.

Comment: Based on the pictures I received, no

Comment: Is there a particular law you are worried about? The only parenting laws I've ever heard of would use general terms, i.e. you may not neglect your children. They'd never mandate that a bedroom has to have toys in it! Though if your children have no toys *at all*, that will be taken into account when deciding whether you are neglectful, for example.

Comment: How much other space do the kids have available to them for healthy childhood activities such as playing with toys, running around, and so on?  How much time do they actually spend in the room?  Have you consulted any Illinois family law specialists?  What did they say?

Comment: Are the children all of the same gender?